# reduce python dictionary values if key meets condition

Tags: python

I have a python dictionary with string keys, integer values.  I want to find the sum of values if the key is not '?'.  I can find the sum using a for loop like this.

```
d = {'a':20, 'b': 20, '?': 10}
sum = 0
for k in d.keys():
    if k != '?':
        sum += d[k]
print "This is my sum: " + sum
```

For ambition's sake only, I would really like to refactor that into a reduce() function.  I took a stab at it:

```
sum = reduce(lambda s, k: s if k == '?' else s += d[k], d.keys())
```

but I don't really know what I'm doing.  I'm sure someone with better functional chops than I can do this in minutes.  Help me out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just use the built-in [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum):

```
>>> d = {'a':20, 'b': 20, '?': 10}
>>> sum(value for key, value in d.items() if key != "?") 
40
```

Answer (score 5):

Since the key `'?'` can appear only one or zero times, just substract the value for that key from the sum:

```
>>> sum(d.values()) - d.get('?', 0)
40
```